# How can I use File::ChangeNotify on Windows?

Tags: perl, winapi

I installed [File::ChangeNotify](https://metacpan.org/module/File::ChangeNotify) on Windows System and try to run the following code :

```
my $watcher =
     File::ChangeNotify->instantiate_watcher
         ( directories => [ 'C:\files' ],
             filter  => qr/\.txt$/
         );


 # # blocking
 while ( my @events = $watcher->wait_for_events() ) { print "new event"}
```

When I ran the script and try to create a new `.txt` file or modify a `.txt` file  under `c:\files` the script didn't print anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works for me (on linux) if I add this line:

```
$| = 1;
```

Then I see `new event`.

Refer to [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html): `$|` or `$OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH`

Here is the complete code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::ChangeNotify;

$| = 1;

my $watcher =
     File::ChangeNotify->instantiate_watcher
         ( directories => [ 'C:\files' ],
             filter  => qr/\.txt$/
         );


 # # blocking
 while ( my @events = $watcher->wait_for_events() ) { print "new event"}
```

UPDATE: As cjm astutely points out, adding a newline works as an alternative to `$|`:

```
 while ( my @events = $watcher->wait_for_events() ) { print "new event\n"}
```

Comment: Or `print "new event\n"`